# Publish report using multiple html file- Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have two questions here in 'Publish Html report'

1) I am trying to publish html Report from multiple html folders where the name of the html file is same in all the folders.
Please suggest on how to declare multiple html files which has the same name through 'Publish HTML Report' .

2)Is there a way to ignore error ,if some times there is no html file in any of the folder path , on publishing the HTML report.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is, "Add" multiple reports under "Publish HTML Reports".

The reports folder path is relative to workspace. You have to mention report path folder, file name(s) and report title.

No, since you have identical filenames, I assume, file path is surely different and report title will vary too. So, adding multiple "Publish HTML Report" should work.

Regarding your question about ignoring the report, there is option under "Publishing options" as "Allow missing report".

> Allow missing report - if false, build will be marked as failed if the
>   report directory does not exist.

Reference : https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Saurabh